# How to root android one without pc?

Tags: root-access, stock-android

[image]

When i try to root my spice dream uno mi 498 without pc with kingroot it give me the error aboveplease prefer another app or give the solution
I am begging please!

Device: spice dream uno (android one)
App: king root.apk
Problem: not rooting 
Problem description: failed  to root

Comment: Isn't your bootloader unlockable? See this: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/205706/why-arent-the-rooting-apps-not-working-anymore

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a PC 
Please have a look at this question recently asked, it brings clarity to the causes of a failure.
[Why don't root apps work anymore ?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/205706/157947)

So after you understand that, you can unlock your bootloader and install a custom recovery, then flash a Systemless root like SuperSU or Magisk

Please follow the complete guide for your device ..
[Unlock Bootloader - Install CWM - Root with SuperSU guides](https://www.theandroidsoul.com/root-spice-dream-uno-easily-supersu-app/)

Comment: Sir, please understand that my usb port is damaged and i am no longer able to connect it to pc please give a solution without pc please.

Comment: And it is now showing please wait for the update

Comment: Sir please reply

Comment: Without Fastboot access via USB .. I'm sure you are going to have difficulties.

Comment: ADB runs via WiFi .. However Fastboot ( Used for Unlocking the Bootloader ) is only accessible via USB as far as I know... You could have used an OTG cable and another tablet ( No PC ) but that still requires USB Access.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've looked high and low, and this is all I could find...

WORST METHOD 
Try using KingRoot v7.3 or above ...

BEST METHOD 
From [mobilespecs.net/](http://mobilespecs.net/phone/root/Spice/Spice_Dream_UNO_Mi-498.html)

**What are the dangers of getting root access?**

1. canceled the warranty
2. you will not receive updates over Wi-Fi
3. in some cases, the procedure for obtaining root access threatens the failure of your device (but most of the gadget can be revived).

**To gain root via "Framaroot"**

1. Download the latest version from the page "Framaroot".
2. Install the program from the downloaded apk-file to your device.
3. Run the utility. In that case, if the device is supported by the program, on the main screen you will see a drop-down list of possible actions, which include options for the removal and root. In addition, below there is one or more exploits titles that are available for use.
4. Tapnite one of the available exploits and tooltip will appear after a few seconds, describing the results of his work. If one method does not work, try another. Sometimes it happens that in the preparation of the superuser "Framaroot" crash randomly. In this case, simply restart the program and try again.
5. Once you get a hint that the device successfully root, you must restart the device.

I'm not sure if that is device specific however..

Other's say try Towelroot, KingoRoot etc..

You could try to use some sort of Universal Signature to sign an update package and the apply the update using the default OTA firmware via SD Card Update, but I'm sure that the universal signature vulnerability or  whatever they called it, has been patched now.